# Batch script wildcards or % for directory reading?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So this script deletes all Chrome data if we provide the full path. But is there anyway to use the wildcard instead of changing user name all the time? I have like 40 users in a server. * and %% does not work at all. Any suggestions?

```
    @echo off
    set ChromeDir=C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
    del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
    rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"
    cls
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    @echo "Success Message"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK 
    exit0
    ) ELSE (
    @echo "Error Message"
    TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK 
    exit 1001
    )
```

Comment: `%USERNAME%` ... Oh wait – are all of these users on the same computer?

Comment: yes all the users are on the same computer

Answer (score 2):

I've got a few suggestions that can help you.  First, indent your code to make it more readable.  Not everything in batch has to be left justified.  Second, use `for /d` to loop through directories.  Third, delayed expansion is necessary if you set a variable and reference that variable within the same code block.  (Although setting `!ChromeDir!` is not crucial, it makes the code a little cleaner I think.)

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "errors=0"

for /d %%I in ("C:\Users\*") do (

    set "ChromeDir=%%~I\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache"

    if exist "!ChromeDir!" (

        rem // Conditional execution increments %errors% if rd exits non-zero
        rd /q /s "!ChromeDir!" || set /a errors += 1
    )
)

echo %errors% errors encountered.

TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK
exit /b %errors%
```

Comment: Okay sounds good. Now instead of User Data, I want to find a way to do delete just the cache. I'll google it.

Comment: I think it would be AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Comment: Okie doke.  I appended `Default\Cache` to the end of `set "ChromeDir=...`.

Comment: I get access is denied message.  Should we add del /q /s /f too it?

Comment: Never mind. It was because the Chrome was opened. Its working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't upvote right now. need 15 reputation it seems. Will upvote once i earn it.